# How is this site preforming an action when you get to a certain part of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I went to a website http://wishbone.org/ and when you get to a graphic of a bunch of cartoon people it changes color, but it starts when you reach it. There's not predetermined time. How do they do that?

Comment: [Stick people](http://www.stickpage.com/stickfights.shtml). Kewl!

Comment: [Stack Overflow does not reverse-engineer other people's software](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131866/143302)

Comment: I think it's a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: It looks like they are using an interesting mix of css and html, and I would just like to learn how they did it.

Comment: I think it's a good question, because it's an increasingly common feature of many news sites, etc; it's not localized at all.

Comment: @Pointy It would be a legitimate question if it contained any code that the OP had difficulties to understand while analyzing the site. As it stands the question doesn't show much effort. The only possible advice is: "Use The Force - Read The Source".

Comment: Well yes, that's true, but on the other hand it is (or could be) a case of having a clear understanding of everything *except* a key ingredient. In this case the answer is simple and concise. To put it another way, if the OP had no idea how to do it, he/she could have posted the most fantastic code sample ever, but it wouldn't help understand the problem at all.

Comment: @Pointy soooooo too localized? ;)\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to handle "scroll" events and wait for a a particular element to become visible, or for the scroll "top" distance to reach a certain minimum.